# Ubuntu 16.04 keeps saying 'out of boot space'

Tags: linux

Every time I boot or log in I get system message that says there is no more free space left in the boot partition.  There is 384MB in the boot partition.  Yes, they appear all used up when using the disk analyzer tool.  There is nothing I did consciously to cause this.  It is a single boot system with nothing fancy loading on startup.

How to allocate more space on this boot partition?  Which set of commands or tools should I use?

Comment: Post output of df for your system.

Comment: @jasonwryan On Ubuntu 16.04, kernel updates remove old unused kernels. AFAIK you get at most  3 kernels there: the latest installed, the one you booted on, and the previous kernel you booted on. If there are more there is a problem with the installation or the package management.

Comment: When you have an error report the error exactly as displayed, do not paraphrase it. Also as asked a `df` result would be useful. And what is the "disk analyzer" tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get rid of a bunch of old kernels and the associated initramfs and system map files: just keep the latest two. The latest one is presumably what you boot normally and the previous one might be useful for debugging if there is a problem.